# How to show Android ListView item in different layout file when clicked

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am making an app in which i want to show some quotes and sayings in a list view and i want to Display each Quote in new layout File when user click on any item in ListView item.This my code for Main Activity with simple listview:-

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ListActivity extends Activity {
    private String[] quoteArray = { "Quote1", "Quote2", "Quote3", "Quote4", "Quote5" };
private ListView quoteListView;
private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

    quoteListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.months_list);

    // this-The current activity context.
    // Second param is the resource Id for list layout row item
    // Third param is input array 
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, quoteArray);
    quoteListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an onItemClickListener():

```
quoteListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //there you start new Activity    
        //you can choose quote by using position paramter    
        }
    });
```

Comment: followed your suggestion but as a beginner i didn't get how to show particular list item in new layout.Suppose user click on Quote1 then then how to show "Quote1"  in a new layout file. Help me please

Comment: You should start new Activity and put Extras.

Intent newIntent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, QuoteActivity.class);
newIntent.putExtra("quote", postion);
startActivity(newIntent);

In new Activity in onCreate method use:
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
int whichQuote;
whichQuote =  extras.getInt("quote", 0);

Comment: after following this method , i think i am almost done but getting an error:-
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: when receiving in another activity